# WCF client threads

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF services can call their clients' methods to get or give data. The question is - which thread on the client will handle the call? A new one?

Comment: Why don't you test it out. That should give you a practical insight into the workings of WCF. Sure enough a theoretical explanation would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

normaly the client will call a proxy for the service and if you don't use asynchronous calls the method will block and the result will of course be on the same thread. - On the service side on the other hand it somewhat depends on your configuration - normaly WCF will spawn tasks or threadpool-threads so you cannot say on which thread it will be handled in the end...

Comment: well thank you - but you don't have to comment on every reply - just upvote those that helps you and mark the best one for you as *the* answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends whether the call is a synchronous or an asynchronous one. For async calls, for instance while using silverlight, the data is received in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CallBackBehavior attribute and "decorate" your callback with [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)], the callback will be executed on a background thread and not the same thread as the one that made the service call initially (which is the default behavior).

Comment: And what will be if service calls its clients on its own (with a timer or whatever), without initial call from a client?